# How to import a .psd1 in a .psm1 using classes?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to require a .dll inside a .psm1 module.

*I am using PS classes*. So, my .psm1 module is a class and I'm trying to use a method from the dll inside that class.

I have the the .psd1 require the dll like this:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @('..\Assets\dll\Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.dll')
```

When I run my script (I am running it from another .ps1 that is *using module myModule.psm1*), I get this error:

```
Unable to find type [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the `using` directive to `using module myModule`, forcing PowerShell to discover the `psd1` rather than the contained `psm1`

Comment: using module is what I am using.. I wrote that in my question.

Comment: Yes, but there's a huge difference between `using module .\myModule.psm1` and `using module myModule` - the first will load the `psm1` module file directly (meaning the requirements are never assessed), whereas the latter forces PowerShell to use regular module discovery and resolve the `psd1` (thereby ensuring all the requirements are processed before importing the psm1)

Comment: Without .psm1 I get ParserError, could not find module.

Comment: The module is in another folder. Hence, I am using a path to it in my using module statement.

Comment: It sounds like the module is not actually installed in a valid module location? Make sure it's discoverable (eg. module folder is placed in an `$env:PSModulePath` path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `using module 'myModule.psm1'`
use `using module 'myModule.psd1'`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).